# Making a comparator consistent with equals

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, comparator, compareto

I am still learning the ropes on that one, but I am trying to implement a comparator for a HashMap to sort the keys using compareTo. To make the comparator consistent with equals I thought to try and catch the int result from compareTo and see if it equals to 0. If it does, check if the objects are equal. The problem I ran into is what happens if the objects are not equal? What would I have to return?

Comment: By assuming the class implements `Comparable`, and the definition of `compareTo()` and `equals()`, if `compareTo()` is zero, then `equals()` MUST return true... and its converse.  In a separate comparator there's no such requirement, you can define ordering however you like.  It's not exactly clear what you're asking.

Comment: Note that you _don't_ need a comparator for `HashMap`. You _do_ have to ensure that every two objects that are `equals` have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: This really depends on the kinds of objects you're dealing with.  A good example of a class where `equals` and `compareTo` give different results is `BigDecimal` - its `compareTo` method compares the values of two numbers, but its `equals` also checks the scale (that is, how many decimal places or significant figures are given).  Now if you're dealing with such a class, you'd have to decide what to do when two numbers have the same numerical value, but different scale.  Like, would your modified `compareTo` make `3.25 < 3.2500` or `3.25 > 3.2500`.  You'd have to decide which makes more sense.

Comment: You are confusing responsibilities. It’s the duty of the `compareTo` method to always return zero for equal objects.

Answer (score 1):

> An int value: 0 if the string is equal to the other string.
> < 0 if the string is lexicographically less than the other string
> 0 if the string is lexicographically greater than the other string (more characters)

hence you could return 0 for equality, 1 for greater than and -1 for less than